# HP Netbook restarting services even when disabled

Tags: windows-7, laptop, netbook

I'm helping a friend try to gain some free RAM and CPU on his HP Mini Notebook. I primarily work on a Mac but am literate on Windows as well. I went to msconfig to see what all was starting and stopped Java Web Start, HP CloudDrive (ZumaDrive), iTunes and Quicktime, and some others.

My question today is, when I restarted the computer after applying the settings, Java web start and zuma drive started up again eventhough I disabled them from startup. For Java, I forced quit it and it opened right back up again.

Why would these services start and restart automatically even though I'm disabling them from startup and forcing quit them. Would HP services be monitoring these and restarting them where needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Autoruns to see where they are starting, and use it to disable them. I doubt that some HP service is restarting them: Either your changes did not take, or they are being started in two different ways (like in the Run registry, and Startup folder, for example). Autoruns will show you everything that is starting, and where it is.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902

Comment: You can also run any of the sysinternals tools from their network share at `\\live.sysinternals.com\tools\<name>.exe`

Comment: @Soumya92 WOW, that is SO cool. Thank you, I never knew that. Of course, if you just want a list, enter \\live.sysinternals.com\tools\

Comment: Or use the built in Windows Defender's Software Explorer.

Comment: These are all very helpful! I will try all of these tonight when I get home and report back.